# How does AutoHotkey determine which executable is launchable with a mere `.exe` name?

Tags: windows, automation, exe, autohotkey, executable

In my experience, `#f::Run mailmaster` will launch `mailmaster.exe` when pressing `#f`, but throws when doing `#f::Run QQMusic`:

[image]

I had to provide the full path for `QQMusic.exe` whereas I didn't have to provide the full path for `mailmaster.exe`.

According to [the documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#ExBasic):

> Run can launch *Windows system programs* from any directory. Note that executable file extensions such as .exe can be omitted.
>
> `Run notepad`

Since both `mailmaster.exe` and `QQMusic.exe` are *non-system programs* and they *are **not** included in the `Path` environment variable*, why AutoHotkey is giving different behaviors for them?

And performance-wise, providing the full path versus just the `.exe` name, which is faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's specified in the documentation:

> **Target**
>
> A document, URL, executable file (.exe, .com, .bat, etc.), shortcut (.lnk), or system verb to launch (see remarks). If *Target* is a local file and no path was specified with it, [A_WorkingDir](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm#verbs) will be searched first. If no matching file is found there, the system will search for and launch the file if it is integrated ("known"), e.g. by being contained in one of the PATH folders.

So pretty much if it's found in PATH.
You can try this for example by typing notepad, mailmaster and QQMusic in cmd or powershell. Notepad is found in PATH, and on your system I'm assuming mailmaster is as well, and QQMusic isn't.
You should get the same results as with the AHK `Run` command.

As for performance, I don't know, I guess this is something you could benchmark.
I'd guess that providing the full path is more efficient.
But maybe finding something from PATH is very well optimized on the the Windows side of things, so maybe there is little to no difference.

Comment: Thanks, the strange thing is both `mailmaster` and `QQMusic` are not found when using the command line whereas `notepad` can be found.

Comment: And I just checked both system environment variables and user ones, they are not included in the `Path`. Not sure why AHK could recognize `mailmaster.exe`.

Comment: Hmm, I guess it's some deeper magic then. The quoted part of the documentation did say "e.g" when mentioning PATH, so there's something else as well. If you're really interested, maybe you could find the answer from the AHK source code.